# redirect component in joomla doesn't work

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo, redirect

When i redirect a page to another page in redirect component, It doesn't work.

in my site when i write something at the end of the url, it redirects on the home page.
for example

```
http://www.farafan-market.ir/fa/fgjdfgjdfsgj
```

redirects on

```
http://www.farafan-market.ir/fa/
```

the same thing happens with the URLs that i redirect in the redirect component. :/

What is the problem? How can i fix it?
I'm using the last version of joomla.

Answer (score 4):

From the Joomla documentation:

> "This component is primarily used for redirecting URLs for web pages that no longer exist on your website to web pages that are working. The URL you want to redirect from must not be a working one on your website which actually loads a web page."

```
https://docs.joomla.org/Help36:Components_Redirect_Manager
```

If the page you are trying to redirect is a working page, you will need to do so in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that the system redirect plugin is activated

Comment: it is activated, does the ordering matter?